# How can I make a gameObject rotate while jumping, then once it collides with another gameObject, return smoothly to its original rotation?

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

How can I make a gameObject rotate while jumping "in the air", then once it collides with another gameObject, return smoothly to its original rotation like shown in the following video: https://youtu.be/iOV0Apuwj94

I do not want the cube to abruptly return to its original rotation once it has collided with something. Like in the video, the cube's rotation is just right when it collides (when it hits the ground, it feels natural). I also want the cube to know where the future collision is, so that it can modify speed, rotation etc. depending on the positions of each gameObject (this way, the rotation would be always correct too).

I have tried many times fine tuning the rotation, but I always fail to get it just right (+predicting future collisions is unknown to me). I do not have the experience to accomplish such a task and searching the Web did not help either. I would appreciate any lines of code, guidance or help from the community. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudocode I can think of which might work for you:

```
while(cube.y> 0)//or greater than the right value of y
{
if(cube.y= 0)//or the right value of y
  {//stop performing rotation}
//perform rotation
}
```

This might just solve all your problems, since you are using a RigidBody for the cube which has a collider and it should automatically align to the ground due to gravity, in my opinion, making it feel even more natural.

Comment: Combined, do these two accomplish the same thing as your suggestion (is it better?)                                                                                 
1) A raycast towards a specific direction to get the distance between next collision and the player.

2) A method which smoothly interpolates between the starting rotation and ending rotation. Then you can calculate the duration (distance to collision / player velocity) and modify the lerp duration which in turn changes the animation speed.

Comment: I do not understand your code, can you write another clearer one?

Comment: I'll get back to you ASAP, sorry for the delay. Might take a while though.

Comment: I need you to post your code so I can get a reference.

Comment: What do you mean? Write another question?

Comment: I'll get back to you in the future, my friend. I'm too busy these days. Sorry for the inconvenience.